# Toggling multiple elements at once

Tags: javascript, html, css

This simple fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qLy74d8a/2/

Is there an easy way of making the one clicked turn blue and then if another is clicked that one turns blue and the first turns back to black i.e. so that only one is blue at any one time?

```
turnBlue() {
    number = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
}
```

Comment: Google "click event handlers" and have a read, it will help you

Comment: I guess it's similar to radio buttons but not in a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated version of your fiddle that will turn the clicked element blue and the last element clicked before that back to black: https://jsfiddle.net/2qam25u1/

```
var previousTarget;
function turnBlue(event) {
    if (previousTarget) {
    previousTarget.className = "";
  }

    event.target.className = "blue";
  previousTarget = event.target;
}
```

The `previousTarget` variable is wrapped by the `turnBlue` function, and in this case is acting as a global state variable. The `turnBlue` function uses the `event` parameter provided by the browser to find the element clicked and this element is saved into `previousTarget` so that we can revert the change when the next element is clicked.